# ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool database connection error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-administration

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.
The following message may help `enter code here`in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
here my connection string in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MusicStore;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

user localhost like 127.0.0.1 it's should be work

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=MusicStore;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: thanks but it still does not work,i move on that topic for now.

Answer (score 0):

set Data Source= your computer name instead of .

Comment: i am not sure that is the problem but i'll try.

Comment: Unfortunately, if setting it to localhost or 127.0.0.1 didn't work, this won't either. They're equivalent. Can you connect to the server itself, just not the database?